# How to get UID and GID in jnrfuse

Tags: fuse, jnr

I am implementing filesytem using fuse and jnrfuse.Can someone tell me how to get the UID and GID info in jnrfuse?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in `fuse_context` which contains `uid`/`gid` then you need to call [`getContext`](https://github.com/SerCeMan/jnr-fuse/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/serce/jnrfuse/AbstractFuseFS.java#L81).

If you want to get `uid`/`gid` outside a fuse method, then you can take a look at [jnr-posix](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix). You are interested in [LibC](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix/blob/master/src/main/java/jnr/posix/LibC.java).

Here is an example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LibC libc = LibraryLoader.create(LibC.class).load("c");

    System.out.println(libc.getuid()); // uid
    System.out.println(libc.getgid()); // gid
}
```